# How to see every packet that comes to our computer?

Tags: python, network-programming

i wrote a very very easy script that monitors the Downloads folder for .part files, if there isn't any then it shuts down the computer and sends an email or text message. But i want to develop it by analyzing the packets to do that i need every packet that comes to our computer. How can i do that? or is there an easier way?

(If you download a file with Firefox or Chrome you will have a .part file which disappears when the download is finished.)
(www.github.com/berkQ/bdown/ for script.)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by analyzing every packet?

Comment: i just want to check if there is a downloading on progress. i thought i can analyze the packets so i can understand when the download is finished. as i said, it would be great if you share an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is an easier way.

The cleanest I can think off would be monitoring the file system.

On linux you could use `pyinotify` : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyinotify/
https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/loop.py

On windows there are alternatives : http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

You could as well write your own file watcher.

Every n seconds and For every file in downloads, get it's size. See if it has changed since last loop, if yes, assume there still are downloads.
If nothing changed during n loops, assume downloads are over.

Comment: I know i shouldn't reply with a "Thanks." but i just can't feel comfortable when i don't say thank you to someone who helped me. So, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are most welcome.
Also if you really want to check network i/o, i'd recommend using this : https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#network